# I cannot import a function within the same file in Django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/calcu.css' %}">

</head>

<form id="calci_form" method="get" action="operation">
<label class="l1">Number 1</label><input type="text" name="num1" class="tb1" value="{{fvalue}}">
<label class="l2">Number 2</label><input type="text" name="num2" class="tb2" value="{{svalue}}">
<label class="l3">Result</label><input type="text" class="tb3" name="user_input" value={{result}}>
 <input type="submit" name="sym" class="btn1" value="Calculate">      
</form>
</html>
```

the above is my html page in Django - calculate.html

I am new to django and I am just trying to add a function to print the sum of two numbers.

the function is in add.py -

```
def add(a,b):
 return a + b
```

The function I am calling this from is in views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from add import add
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, "calculate.html")




def operation(request):
  if 'sym' in request.GET:
            first = int(request.GET['num1'])
            second = int(request.GET['num2'])
            res = add(first,second)
            context = {
                'fvalue': first,
                'svalue': second,
                'result': res,

            }
            return render(request,'calculate.html', context)
```

now the add.py is in the same folder as views.py. However it says "The site can't be reached"

Don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you please provide your `settings.py` ?

Comment: The error you mentioned seems to be unrelated to the problem you described, it's probably saying that your Django server is not running, maybe because of another error. Try running `runserver` again and check the output, if an error comes out, share it.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you guys